# How to write unit test class for my Rest controller with JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am new to Spring boot and junit. I have a Rest service in Spring Boot where I receive the request, use the request parameter to query database, receive result from query and send it as response.

My  controller code is like this:

```
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate mTemplate;

@GetMapping("/myservice")
    public String getGreeting2(@RequestParam(value = "name") String name) {
        //DO the query using mTemplate;
    }
```

My JdbcTemplate is isntantiated as a bean in a separate class like this

```
@Bean
public JdbcTemplate dataSource(){
         BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
         ds.setDriverClassName(....);
         ds.setUrl(...);
         ds.setUserName(...);
         ds.setPassword(...);
         return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
}
```

My code runs fine.

Now I want to write unit test for my controller using JUnit4.
I use MockMvc to send request, but my unit test never takes off.
It always  throws exception saying, "Unable to resolve bean data source....Unable to load suitable driver class"

I have tried providing datasource details in a application.properties file inside src/test/java, but it doesn't work. I think I am missing some fundamental process. Please guide me on what are the steps one needs to take to write junit test for rest controller with data source. Something Like this:

```
@Runwith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MyRestControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void getHello() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/myservice").param("name", "..."))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
                
    }
```

P.S. With no data source in the main class of Rest controller, the tests run fine.

Comment: Don't unit test controllers, or access the database directly from the controller. Separate the application into tiers with distinct responsibilities - the controller is just for requests and responses, not business or persistence logic. You can use e.g. [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) to easily stand up isolated databases for integration testing, which is a more appropriate level for ensuring the controllers are doing the right thing *in concert with other components*.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do in this case is an integration test, try with this annotations in your test class:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
    @WebAppConfiguration
```

But maybe you would like to just make a test of your controller, in this case, you can Mock the JdbcTemplate like this:

```
    @InjectMocks
    private YourController yourController;

    @Mock
    private JdbcTemplate mTemplate;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        MonitoringHelper.initMocks();
        intelligencePostFilter = new IntelligencePostFilter(intelligenceService);
        when(mTemplate.methodX()).thenReturn(....);
    }
```

In this case, with no annotations for the test class